# Password with a colon fails basic auth?

Tags: java

I'm using basic auth. If my password contains a colon, I seem to get a failure to authenticate. Are colons not allowed in a password? How I'm authenticating:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpRequestInterceptor preemptiveAuth = new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
    ...
};
client.addRequestInterceptor(preemptiveAuth, 0);
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
  new AuthScope("example.com", 443),
  new UsernamePasswordCredentials("me", "password:test"));
```

Passwords without a colon always work. Passwords with a colon always fail. Do I have to escape the password somehow before handing it to the UsernamePasswordCredentials class constructor? I know basicauth uses the username/password separated by a colon, then base64 encoded, is that what the problem is here?

Thanks

---- Update ------

Thanks all, yes was a problem in the server I was communicating with!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It should work. [RFC2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) is the RFC around HTTP authentication. The spec does not place any restriction on the characters used within a password, only on the username;

To receive authorization, the client sends the userid and password,
   separated by a single colon (":") character, within a base64 [7]
   encoded string in the credentials.

```
  basic-credentials = base64-user-pass
  base64-user-pass  = <base64 [4] encoding of user-pass,
                      except not limited to 76 char/line>
  user-pass   = userid ":" password
  userid      = *<TEXT excluding ":">
  password    = *TEXT
```

Comment: The separation of the user name and the password is being done at the first position of colon in the decrypted string I think. So, can user name contain a colon, and still be unscathed?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ The grammar rule `userid = *<TEXT excluding ":">`  makes it clear that a user-name *cannot* contain a colon.

Comment: Is there any solution for this ?? Can username or password contain ":" or not ?

Comment: *Update*: As of September 2015 RFC2617 is obsoleted by (among others) [RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617.html) which now provides more details on characters allowed in user id and password:

`For the user-id, recipients MUST support all characters [...] with the exception of the colon (":") character.

   For the password, recipients MUST support all characters defined in
   the "OpaqueString" profile defined in Section 4.2 of [RFC7613].
`

So the solution for OP nowadays  would be for the server to split decoded Basic auth token by the first colon character.

Answer (score 6):

If the server has a bug in separating that Base64 "username:password", the authentication method will fail. Either check on your server (perhaps there are updates available? go with a different server?), don't use a colon in your passwords, or use a different authentication method.

Out of curiosity, what server are you trying to authenticate against?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but in case others run into the same issue:

The code in `new UsernamePasswordCredentials("me", "password:test"));` might split the string on every colon.  Here is an example in PHP that would fail:

```
 $bits = explode(':',$auth_string);
 $user = $bits[0];
 $password = $bits[1];
```

Here is a fix:

```
 $bits = explode(':',$auth_string);
 $user = array_shift($bits);
 $password = implode(':',$bits);
```

Comment: Note that [the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) `explode()` also accepts `$limit` as a third element. The fix can be simplified to this: `$bits = explode(':', $auth_string, 2); $user = $bits[0]; $password = $bits[1];`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had an issue with a colon in the password. Seems like the username and password won't be splitted correctly.

Example **user:pass:word**

In my case the delivered Password in PHP was just "pass" instead of "pass:word".

I've learned to avoid special chars like : (colon) and @ (at) in the password. It's a bit strange, because the same logic worked correctly before we've updated to php-fpm (I don't know if this issue belongs to php-fpm).